# Is it possible to get animations within a storyboard to execute in serial

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, animation

I have a number of animations that I would like to execute on the Loaded event of a control:

```
 <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
     <BeginStoryboard>
         <Storyboard>                                
             <DoubleAnimation ...
             <DoubleAnimation ...
             <DoubleAnimation ...
```

What I would like to do is execute the first two in parallel (which seems to be the default behaviour), and the last once they have finished.  Is this possible and, if so, how?

Comment: What about [BeginTime Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.begintime.aspx)?

Comment: Excellent advice - I ended up using this. It might not be as textbook as other approaches, but it works, it's simple, and it's easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

The Blend "interactivity" DLLs support this scenario.  Set a [StoryboardCompletedTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.media.storyboardcompletedtrigger%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) on the first storyboard, with a [ControlStoryboardAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.media.controlstoryboardaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) on the second.  For example (note that this requires references to System.Windows.Interactivity.dll and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
     xmlns:em="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Media;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
     xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="FirstStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation ...
            <DoubleAnimation ...
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Name="SecondStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation ...
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <em:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource FirstStoryboard}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>

        <em:StoryboardCompletedTrigger Storyboard="{StaticResource FirstStoryboard}">
            <em:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource SecondStoryboard}" />
        </em:StoryboardCompletedTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Grid>
```